# How to stop bluetooth from scanning repeated found devices and how to use ScanFilter to restrict scan results

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to create an indoor location app to detect own location and wayfinding. I have already set up my bluetooth app to scan and display found devices and beacons. However i found out that some of the devices found were repeated. What do i need to do to stop it and i wanted to find only certain devices mac address. May i know how to use the method `ScanFilter` and what is the difference between `ScanFilter` and `ScanFilter.Builder`? Do i need to implement `ScanSetting`?

i have try putting this

```java
ScanFilter scanFilterMac = new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceAddress("88:88:88:B0:03:DB").build();
```

I change the mac address only but didn't get any result. and can i do something like this since i know the first 6 digit is the same

```
ScanFilter scanFilterMac = new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceAddress("68:54:F5:([A-Fa-f0-9]{2}:){2}([A-Fa- 
f0-9]{2})").build();
```

```java
    public void startScanning() {

        final BluetoothLeScanner btScanner = btAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
        if (btScanner == null) {
            // not enabled yet or not supported
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("start scanning");
        peripheralTextView.setText("");
        startScanningButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        stopScanningButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ScanFilter scanFilterMac = new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceAddress("68:54:F5:88:88:88").build();
                listFilter.add(scanFilterMac);
                btScanner.startScan(listFilter,leScanCallback);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: create a `Set` to track the `connected device` while in CanCallback implementation, only connect non-connected devices.

Comment: how to create a set to track the connected device? and do you mean in ScanCallback implementaion?

Comment: your leScanCallback is the ScanCallback. A Java Hashset of string, add connected device’s name and later compare it with new found device’s name

Comment: can you show me an example of it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
final class BleScanCallback extends ScanCallback {
  // address -> device map
  private final Map<String, BluetoothDevice> scanResults;

  public void onScanResult(int callbackType,  ScanResult result) {
     this.addScanResult(result);
  }

  public void onBatchScanResults( List results) {
     for (final Object result1 : results) {
        ScanResult result = (ScanResult) result1;
        this.addScanResult(result);
     }

  }

  public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
  }

  private void addScanResult(ScanResult result) {
     BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();
     String name = device.getName();
     if (name != null  && !this.scanResults.containsKey(device.getAddress())) {
        String var6 = device.getAddress();
        this.scanResults.put(var6, device);
     } else {
        StringBuilder var10001 = (new StringBuilder()).append("Ble addScanResult ignore ");
        Log.d("Ble", var10001.append(device.getName()).append(' ').append(device.getType()).append(' ').append(device.getAddress()).append(' ').toString());
     }

  }

  public BleScanCallback( Map<String, BluetoothDevice> scanResults) {
     super();
     this.scanResults = scanResults;
  }
 }
```